# One server, multiple IP, multiple website, it's possible?

Tags: ip, hosting, web-hosting

I have few website (~5) and I want to host all website on ONE unique server but with multiple IP.

Example:

```
WEB->Server nginx->website1
WEB->Server nginx->website2
WEB->Server nginx->website3
WEB->Server nginx->website4
WEB->Server nginx->website5

Ping website1 == 0.0.0.1
Ping website2 == 0.0.0.2
Ping website3 == 0.0.0.3
Ping website4 == 0.0.0.4
Ping website5 == 0.0.0.5
```

this is possible ?
What kind of hosting company i can use ?

Comment: Yes, it is; use any hosting company that will give you all those addresses.  Be prepared to pay, if you can get them at all, because wanting to run five different HTTP sites isn't a good reason for needing five addresses.

Comment: Do you really need 5 IP addresses or do you just need [name based virtual hosting](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html) ?

Comment: @MadHatter I will use Amazon EC2 with elastic IP, I think they provide 5 eleastic IP for free :)

Comment: @Iain Yep I don't want virtual hosting but real public IP :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should not be a problem at all. You just have to order the needed amount of IP addresses. This means that any hoster can do this. And watch out what you ask: Shopping questions don't live long here... :-)